# Why doesn't the following open set has a tube the lie inside of it

Tags: general-topology

I am reading the following example from Munkres. Let $$N = \left\{ (x,y)\in\mathbb R ^2 : |x| < \frac{1}{y^2 + 1} \right\}.$$ Then $N$ is an open set containing the set $\{0\}\times \mathbb R$, but it contains no tube about $\{0\}\times \mathbb R$. Can someone explain why it doesn't contain a tube ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look what happens to $N$ as you go far up the $y$-axis; as $y$ goes to $\infty$, $1/(y^2 +1)$ goes to $0$, so the $x$ coordinates go to $0$. So there can be   no tube inside $N$.

More formally, let $\epsilon>0$. We show $(-\epsilon,\epsilon) \times \mathbb R$ is not contained in $N$. There exists $y$ such that $\frac{1}{y^2+1}<\epsilon$. Let $x\in (\frac{1}{y^2+1},\epsilon)$. Then $(x,y)\in [(-\epsilon,\epsilon) \times \mathbb R]\setminus N$

Answer (score 0):

A tube has a width, which is a positive number.  In this case, no matter how small a positive number you pick, the width of the symmetric region about the $y$-axis within which the tube must fit gets smaller than that positive number if $|y|$ is big enough.